# Is it possible to install K9 Web Protection on 64-bit Windows?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit

Does anyone know a way to install K9 Web Protection on 64-bit Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blue Coat just released a 64-bit version of K9 Web Protection.  Find it at getk9.com

Answer (score 0):

What version of 64-bit Windows are you interested in?  I have Win 7 x64 Ultimate at home that I'd be happy to try and let you know how it goes.  I also have a Win 2k8 Server x64 that I could try as well.

However, the [support doc](http://www.bluecoat.com/doc/direct/9711) only lists Windows Vista, XP, and 2000.

Comment: I am using Windows 7. Yes, they say it isn't supported, and I've tried it but in vain. That's why I am asking whether someone knows some way to do it. :)